# Linq to Get Values within date Not bringing correct value

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-ajax

I have this Linq query that i want to use to list items with a date range.

the code is below:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string search, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var stDate = startDate.Date;
        var enDate = endDate.Date;
        var str = search;
       
        List<LoanAccount> loanAccounts  = (from loanCustomer in db.LoanAccounts
                                           where (loanCustomer.Account_Number.Contains(search) || search == null) 
                                           && (loanCustomer.Date_Opened >= stDate && loanCustomer.Date_Opened <= enDate)
                                           select loanCustomer).ToList();
        return Json(loanAccounts);
    }
```

If the stdate is 23/01/2021 and endate is 23/01/2021, it does not return values on that day. If i change the enDate to 24/01/2021, It brings the data for 23/01/2021 and will not include for 24/01/2021. Is it that I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`23-01-2021` is the same as `23-01-2021 00:00:00`. So the comparison `23-01-2021 14:00:00 <= 23-01-2021` will therefore be `false`.

In other words, the date range `23-01-2021` to `23-01-2021` is not a range since the start (`23-01-2021 00:00:00`) and end (`23-01-2021 00:00:00`) are the same.

Instead, you need the end-date to be one day later and then only take everything that is strictly less than the end date. So the range would be `23-01-2021` to `24-01-2021`, which is essentially `23-01-2021 00:00:00` to `24-01-2021 00:00:00`.

Your solution should therefore be:

```
var stDate = startDate.Date;
var enDate = endDate.Date.AddDays(1);
var str = search;

List<LoanAccount> loanAccounts  =
    (from loanCustomer in db.LoanAccounts
    where (loanCustomer.Account_Number.Contains(search) || search == null)
    //                          Notice the "strictly less" comparison  v
    && (loanCustomer.Date_Opened >= stDate && loanCustomer.Date_Opened < enDate)
    select loanCustomer).ToList();
```

Comment: I have used the < less than before and it is same thing. I just used it now self. the Field DATE_OPENED is Datetime

Comment: @uthumvc Also after setting `enDate = endDate.Date.AddDays(1)` like in my example?

Comment: Oh. I missed that, Let me try it

Comment: It is working fine now. But why must we put that .AddDays(1).

Comment: @uthumvc I added some details to the answer, hopefully that makes it clearer

Answer (score 1):

DateDiffDay function counts the number of day between the startDate and endDate.
So you can try this:

```
 where (loanCustomer.Account_Number.Contains(search) || search == null)
       && EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(stDate, loanCustomer.Date_Opened)>=0 
       && EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(loanCustomer.Date_Opened, enDate) >=0
```

Comment: Does it mean i dont have to use var enDate = endDate.Date.AddDays(1);

Comment: Yes,  It means that you shouldn't use  AddDays at all. There are also functions DateDiffHour or  DateDiffMinute.